# Making (Mac)Vim reopen with files open when closed

Tags: vim, macvim

Use case:

You have 2-3 files displayed in your MacVim window(s). You press ctrl+Q and MacVim closes.
When you restart MacVim it opens displaying the same files you had when you closed it.

How can you do that?

--
**ANSWER**

I added the following to my .vmirc

```
  "save and close all files and save global session
nnoremap <leader>q :mksession! ~/.vim/Session.vim<CR>:wqa<CR>
  "close all files without saving and save global session
nnoremap <leader>www :mksession! ~/.vim/Session.vim<CR>:qa!<CR>

function! RestoreSession()
  if argc() == 0 "vim called without arguments
    execute 'source ~/.vim/Session.vim'
  end
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call RestoreSession()
```

With this I almost have the exact behavior I wanted, the only minor nuisance is that I still need to press command-q afterwards but that's MacOs, not vim....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you read about sessions `:help session`,that should answer your question. There are even nice scripts to deal with sessions.

Comment: Thank you mb14, I was able to devise what I needed after following your lead

Comment: @gws can you please write your solution ? Thanks.

Comment: @Trickster it is described at the bottom of the answer. I have since stopped using MacVim and moved to terminal vim but the solution was working fine at the time

Answer (score 14):

Install this plugin: https://github.com/xolox/vim-session

And add this following two lines to your `.vimrc` :

```
let g:session_autosave = 'yes'
let g:session_autoload = 'yes'
```

Now if you close your MacVim/GVim it saves and loads the session automatically.

Comment: This works smoothly, but note that it won't restore unsaved/unnamed buffers.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you use [session.vim Extended session management for Vim](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/session/) for session management as this plugin just works. You can automatically save your current session everytime you close vim or create a new session, close/open vim and load that session.