# MacVim blank screen on startup with simple session-restore function

Tags: vim, macvim

So, I've added this function to my `gvimrc`, trying to get MacVim to re-open the same windows / same files, when rebooting.

```
" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955232/making-macvim-reopen-with-files-open-when-closed
" save and close all files and save global session
nnoremap <leader>q :mksession! ~/.vim/gvim-session.vim<CR>:wqa<CR>
" close all files without saving and save global session
nnoremap <leader>www :mksession! ~/.vim/gvim-session.vim<CR>:qa!<CR>

function! RestoreSession()
   if argc() == 0 " vim called without arguments
      let sessionFile='source ~/.vim/gvim-session.vim'
      execute sessionFile
      :call delete(sessionFile)
   end
endfunction
autocmd VimEnter * call RestoreSession()
```

However, now, when I open MacVim, I get a *completely* blank window (that is, not even the `~~~`s denoting blank lines, nor a status-bar or sign column or anything else) until I hit the return key:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my function to cause that. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can and should drop the initial `:` in

   ```
   :call delete(sessionFile)
   ```
2. `delete()` deletes a file but `sessionFile` doesn't point to a file:

   ```
   let sessionFile='source ~/.vim/gvim-session.vim'
   ```

   It should look like that:

   ```
   let sessionFile='~/.vim/gvim-session.vim'
   ```
3. Why did you put `source` in the file path anyway? You could simply do the following:

   ```
   execute "source " . sessionFile
   ```